# Ember.js: Unit testing a helper that has a dependency injection?

Tags: ember.js, ember-qunit

In an initializer, I'm injecting an object into my helper, and it works properly in the App.

But when testing the helper with QUnit, I get the following error:

> TypeError: undefined is not a function.

The helper doesn't have access to the injected object, although when calling `App.__container__.lookup('myObject:main')` within the setup function of the module, it does return the object.

How can I make this work? The test class is based on [fiddle1](http://jsbin.com/ECoTIP/1/edit), [fiddle2](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/uvEVegO/3/edit).

The following example in CoffeeScript shows my problem:

```
App = undefined
entered = false
initializedCount = 0

module 'testing',
  setup: ->
    App = startApp()

  teardown: ->
    Ember.run(App, 'destroy')

Ember.Application.initializer({
  name: "person",
  initialize: (container, application) ->
    initializedCount++;
    person = {
      name: "Mary"
    }
    container.register('person:main', person, {instantiate: false});
    container.injection('helper', 'person', 'person:main');
});

createView = (template, context) ->
  context = {}  unless context
  View = Ember.View.extend(
    controller: context
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile(template)
  )
  View.create()

append = (view) ->
  Ember.run ->
    view.appendTo "#ember-testing"
    return
  return


Ember.Handlebars.helper "upcase", (value) ->
  person = @get('person'); # <-- test fails here
  value += person.name;
  value.toUpperCase()

Ember.testing = true

test('non-redirect route /third', ->
  equal(initializedCount, 2, 'initializer ran');
  App.reset();
  equal(initializedCount, 3, 'initializer ran');
  App.reset();
  equal(initializedCount, 4, 'initializer ran');
);

test "a handlebars helper", ->
  view = createView("{{upcase 'something'}}")
  append view
  equal view.$().text(), "SOMETHING MARY"
  return
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: Which version of Ember do you use?

Answer (score 1):

In recent Ember the `moduleFor()` syntax [has been deprecated](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-qunit/blob/master/docs/migration.md#migrating-from-modulefor-apis), but the `this.owner.lookup()` method that is the migration path for controllers and other instances doesn't seem to return an instance with context for helpers.

I couldn't find any documentation on testing helpers with dependencies, but after [consulting Ember's own testing](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/@ember/-internals/glimmer/tests/integration/helpers/custom-helper-test.js#L690), I found that [`Application.factoryFor()`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/classes/ApplicationInstance/methods/factoryFor?anchor=factoryFor) seems to do the trick:

```
import { module, test } from 'qunit'
import { setupTest } from 'ember-qunit'

module('Unit | Helper | example-helper', function (hooks) {
  setupTest(hooks)
  let exampleHelper
  hooks.beforeEach(function () {
    exampleHelper = this.owner.factoryFor('helper:example-helper').create()
  })
  test('base', function (assert) {
    assert.equal(exampleHelper.compute([params]), 'expected result')
  })
})
```

Using `factoryFor().create()` did construct an instance with the proper context and injected dependencies. I don't know if this is the recommended method or not, but it seems to do what I wanted it to!

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using a service to handle the data.  The service could then be injected into the helper, which could then be unit tested quite easily.

[Helpers in Ember 2.x are now "real" objects and can have access to services](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/11021#issuecomment-161987298).

The service might look something like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend({
  profile: { 
    name: 'mary',
  },
});
```

The helper would receive data from the service via an injection:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Helper.extend({
  person: Ember.inject.service(), // <-- here

  compute(params) {
    const text = params[0];
    const name = this.get('person.profile.name');
    const phrase = `${text} ${name}`;
    return this.upperCase(phrase);
  },

  upperCase(str) {
    return str.toUpperCase();
  },
});
```

And finally, the unit test would merely include the Person service as a required **`need`**:

```
import { moduleFor, test } from 'ember-qunit';

moduleFor('helper:upper-case', {
  needs: [ 'service:person' ], // <-- here
});

test('when the upperCase helper is used', function(assert) {
  const helper = this.subject();
  const result = helper.compute([ 'goodbye' ]);
  const expected = 'GOODBYE MARY';

  assert.equal(result, expected, 
               '...the dependency is injected and all are uppercased');
});
```

Furthermore, the service could also be injected across your application via an initializer, like this:

```
export function initialize(application) {
  application.inject('controller', 'person', 'service:person');
  application.inject('component', 'person', 'service:person');
  application.inject('route', 'person', 'service:person');
  // etc.
}

export default {
  name: 'person',
  initialize,
};
```

I've created an [Ember Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/e99f2ab0ff743bb59ec3d6fff050b661?openFiles=tests.unit.helpers.upper-case-test.js%2C) to demonstrate.